# Can I delete the field '_id' from a document in MondoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to delete the field '_id' as it's giving me a DuplicateKeyError. And i want to do it this way only :-

```
res1 = db.test_collection   
for i in res.find():
   j = i
   j['count'] = count_keywords(i, keywords)
   print j  
   res1.insert_one(j)
```

But in this i want to delete the field '_id' before inserting it in res1.How should i go about doing that?

***Also i want to do it via a python script only!(Not via MongoShell or PythonShell) ***

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: You doing it wrong. show sample document with expected result. They might be better way to do what you want. Aslo please take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is my sample document :-

{'count': 0, u'rating': [], u'genres': [u'Comedy', u'Drama', u'Romance'], u'runtime': [u'\n                98 min\n'], u'title': [u'People Hold On'], u'studios': [u'BrancSeater Productions'], u'metascore': [u'5.4'], u'plot_keywords': [], u'director': [u'Michael Seater'], u'stars': [u'Katie Boland', u'Paula Brancati', u'Mazin Elsadig'], u'year': [u'2015'], u'_id': ObjectId('562368a51da7ee0bea2e3448')} 

And i want to copy this whole document into a variable without including the '_id' field

Answer (score 1):

According to MongoDB documentation

> MongoDB reserves the _id field in the top level of all documents as a
>   primary key. _id must be unique, and always has an index with a unique
>   constraint.

All documents in mongodb consists of _id field which encapsulates  auto generated ObjectId.
MongoDB adds the _id field with the value set to a generated ObjectId upon insertion of new document.